# Moving a Circle in Octave 4.2.1 Using set() and drawCircle()

Tags: animation, octave, gnu

I am attempting to write a code that simulates the motion of each planet around the sun in the solar system using a graph in Octave 4.2.1. One aspect of this project is to have the sun and all the planets on the graph be circles of a certain size (i.e. a specific radius) and to have each circle moving. The problem I am having is using the built-in set() function to set new x and y values for the center of each circle that is already drawn. I do not want to redraw each circle in each iteration of my loop, because it causes very choppy and inconsistent motion, and with the set() function it is very smooth and consistent motion. I have been able to use the set() function for simple point using a handle and the plot() function. But with the function I want to use, which is drawCircle(), using the set() function always returns an error.

Here is a simple version (that is not working) of what I want to do in my actual code:

```
figure 1
  s=drawCircle(0,0,1);
  hold on
  axis([-2 2 -2 2])
  set(s,'x0', 1)
```

This code returns the error: "set: unknown line property x0". To be more specific I am asking how to set the x and y coordinates of the center of the circle drawn with drawCircle() using the set() function, after it is drawn.
I would really appreciate if anyone has any ideas of how to get this to work, or any alternative workarounds to achieve the same thing.

Comment: I do similar things, but I am afraid I have never encountered the current axis property 'x0' you are trying to modify.  If after you draw the circle, you do 'P=get(s);P.x0 what do you find? I get "structure has no member 'x0'".   When you  write "that is not working"  can you specifically state what the output is?

Comment: @ClintonWinant The example I gave returns a similar error that you get. I am basing this on the documentation of Octave's drawCircle() function at this link: [link](https://octave.sourceforge.io/geometry/function/drawCircle.html)
Evidently, this example is simply an attempt I am making to give an example of how I imagine it should work, but it doesn't.

Comment: the handle that is returned by the call to drawCircle is a line handle, (see https://octave.org/doc/v4.0.1/Introduction-to-Graphics-Structures.html#Introduction-to-Graphics-Structures)  looking at these I see no property that would allow the circle to be displaced, as it seems you envision.  It would be most helpful if you would include the code you describe as having worked in the first part of your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to me this does what you want:

```
clear;clf
th=2*pi*linspace(0,1,19);xc=cos(th);yc=sin(th);
h=plot(xc,yc,'linewidth',1);
axis([-2 2 -2 2]);
pause
x=get(h,'xdata');y=get(h,'ydata');
set(h,'xdata',x+1,'ydata',y+0.5)
```

Comment: So to answer the other part of my question, which is the radius, based on your code I got this to work where 'r' is the radius:
`clear;clf
r=0.5;
th=2*pi*linspace(0,1,200);xc=r*cos(th);yc=r*sin(th);
h=plot(xc,yc,'linewidth',1);
axis([-2 2 -2 2]);
pause
x=get(h,'xdata');y=get(h,'ydata');
set(h,'xdata',x+1,'ydata',y+0.5)`